# Get multiple attributes from one left attribute in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

If I have a table like this:

```
UserName | BoardName
-----------------------
Alice   Research
Ethan   Research
Ethan   Gardening
Ethan   Movies
Jack    Travel
Jack    Movies
Tom         Gardening
Tom         Teaching
Tom         Travel
Tom         Movies
Tom         Study
```

Can I get results like this using a PL/SQL query?

```
Alice   Research
Ethan   Research
            Gardening
            Movies
Jack    Travel
            Movies
Tom         Gardening
            Teaching
            Travel
            Movies
            Study
```

Notice how there are blank cells after the UserNames? Sorry if the question is not very clear.

I think a GROUP BY query would work but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT  
     case when UserName=lag(UserName) OVER (ORDER BY UserName) 
     then null 
     else UserName end UserName,
     UserEmail, 
     BoardName
FROM 
     YourTable;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4f31/1)

Comment: While I can't give you an upvote (rep. < 15) but I you are very correct, I got the desired result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    UserName,
    BoardName
FROM
    TheTable
GROUP BY 
    UserName,
    BoardName
```

Will get you

```
John    Cooking
John    Travel
Tom     Cooking
Bill    Sport
```

so the trick is find out the row num in the group and work with that

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by GROUP order by UserName,  BoardName) > 1 THEN ''
       ELSE UserName
    END AS UserName,   
    BoardName
FROM
    TheTable
GROUP BY 
    CASE
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by GROUP order by UserName,  BoardName) > 1 THEN ''
       ELSE UserName
    END,   
    BoardName
```

I don't have oracle so can't test it.

Comment: What I want is to exclude John from appearing again in the second row., I just want a blank in there.